# Finding the invariant sets of a linear autonomous vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following autonomous vector field on the plane: 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
\dot x_1 \\
\dot x_2
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ 
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I'm asked to describe the invariant sets. I know that the equilibria are invariant sets, but are there any others? If there are, how do I go about finding them?